# How to append data on every page (for all results)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code is almost done. Last part im stuck on is appending data from table from every page (by clicking "Next"), for all of the results. The Log-In isn't included for obvious reasons, but I included the "Next" xpath so that should suffice. Thought I should maybe put the actual webscrape code in a loop, but not sure. Any suggestions, on how to include it ("Next")???

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

#driver path
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#access crunchbase ui
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

#next page
pages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@aria-label="Next"]')

for page in pages:
    page.click()
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
    #navigate crunchbase & add parameters
    addcolumn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="mat-focus-indicator add-column-button mat-stroked-button mat-button-base mat-primary"]')
    addcolumn.click()
    
    # get items only from first list
    all_categories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[1]//mat-list-item')
    print('len(all_categories):', len(all_categories))
    
    for category in all_categories:
        print('-----')
        
        # select category
        print('Category:', category.text.strip())
        
        # scroll it to make it visible and clickable
        #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", category)
        # or
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(category).perform()
        
        # click category to display list of columns in this category
        category.click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
        # search columns ONLY in selected category
    
        # it selects item only if `mat-checkbox` doesn't have class `mat-checkbox-checked`
        # and it click `label` instead of `checkbox` because `label` is not hidden by `popup message`
        columns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
        print('len(columns):', len(columns))
    
        for col in columns:
            print('click:', col.text.strip())
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(col).perform()
            
            col.click()
        
        # TODO: click subcategory, select checkboxes, click back button 
        subcategories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[2]//mat-list-item[.//icon[@key="icon_caret_right"]]')
        print('len(subcategories):', len(subcategories))
        for sub in subcategories:
            sub.click()
        
            subcolumns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//mat-nav-list)[3]//mat-checkbox[not(contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked"))]//label')
        
            for subc in subcolumns:
                subc.click()
    
        if subcategories:               
            backbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-dialog-0"]//mat-dialog-content//button')   
            backbutton.click() 
            
            
            
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Apply Changes"]').click()
   
#await element location
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
          (By.XPATH, ('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[2]/div/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div')
        )))

#webscrape through iterations
all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("grid-row")
            
company_list = [] ###create dictionary
                          
for row in all_rows:
   cblist = {
        'company': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="identifier-label"]').text.strip(),
        'industry': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="categories"]//span').text.strip(),
        'hq': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="location_identifiers"]//span').text.strip(),
        'description': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="short_description"]//span').text.strip(),
        'cb rank': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="rank_org"]').text.strip(),
        'cb rank (company)': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="rank_org_company"]').text.strip(),
        'cb rank (school)': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="rank_org_school"]').text.strip(),
        'contact job department': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="contact_job_departments"]').text.strip(),
        'number of contacts': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="num_contacts"]').text.strip(),
        'diversity spotlight (US only)': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="diversity_spotlights"]').text.strip(),
        'founded date': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="founded_on"]').text.strip(),
        'number of investments': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="num_investments_funding_rounds"]').text.strip(),
        'number of diversity investments': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="num_diversity_spotlight_investments"]').text.strip(),
        'number of exits': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="num_exits"]').text.strip(),
        'industry groups': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="category_groups"]').text.strip(),
        'founders': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="founder_identifiers"]').text.strip(),
        'funding status': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="funding_stage"]').text.strip(),
        'transaction name': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="acquisition_identifier"]').text.strip(),
        'acquired by': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="acquirer_identifier"]').text.strip(),
        'announced by': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="acquisition_announced_on"]').text.strip(),
        'price': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="acquisition_price"]').text.strip(),
        'ipo status': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="ipo_status"]').text.strip(),
        'ipo date': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="went_public_on"]').text.strip(),
        'delisted date': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="delisted_on"]').text.strip(),
        'ipo amount raised': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="ipo_amount_raised"]').text.strip(),
        'ipo valuation': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="ipo_valuation"]').text.strip(),
        'stock exchange': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="stock_exchange_symbol"]').text.strip(),
        'last leadership hiring date': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="last_key_employee_change_date"]').text.strip(),
        'last layoff date': row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-columnid="last_layoff_date"]').text.strip()
   }
   company_list.append(cblist)

#create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(company_list)

print(df)

#create excel writer object
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('crunchbase.xlsx')

#export to excel
df.to_excel(writer)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Your idea is to press Next and continue scraping table data?

Comment: @Nikita yes, thats the idea